# Increase space between images using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,fit,shapes,calc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}

\begin{document}

\def\firstcircle{(1.5,0) circle (0.6cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(1.5,0) circle (1cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{black}
\colorlet{circle area}{gray!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick}, outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\begin{figure}
\footnotesize\centering
% Set A and B
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\draw[filled] \firstcircle node { $F$ };
\draw \secondcircle node { };
\node[anchor=south,rectangle] at (current bounding box.north) { All $F$ are $G$ \\ $\forall x(Fx\to Gx)$};
\node at (2.1,0.6) { $G$ };
% \draw (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (4.5,2.5) node [text=black,above] {$\emptyset$};
\draw (5,0) circle (1cm) node { $F$ };
\draw (7.5,0) circle (1cm) node { $G$ };
\node[anchor=south,rectangle] at (6.25,1) { No $F$ are $G$ \\ $\forall x(Fx\to \neg Gx)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
%\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm) node { $F$ };
\draw (1.5,0) circle (1cm) node { $G$ };
\draw (0.8,0) node { \textbf{x} };
\node[anchor=south,rectangle] at (0.75,1) { Some $F$ are $G$ \\ $\exists x(Fx\wedge Gx)$};
\draw (5,0) circle (1cm) node { $F$ };
\draw (6.5,0) circle (1cm) node { $G$ };
\draw (5,-0.65) node { \textbf{x} };
\node[anchor=south,rectangle] at (5.75,1) { Some $F$ are not $G$ \\ $\exists x(Fx\wedge \neg Gx)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{The four standard types of quantified statements\label{venn}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I need to increase the vertical space between the two part of the images as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an invisible coordinate. Adding `\path (0,2);` to the second picture yields

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\firstcircle{(1.5,0) circle (0.6cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(1.5,0) circle (1cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{black}
\colorlet{circle area}{gray!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick}, outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\begin{figure}
\footnotesize\centering
% Set A and B
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\draw[filled] \firstcircle node { $F$ };
\draw \secondcircle node { };
\node[anchor=south,rectangle] at (current bounding box.north) { All $F$ are $G$ \\ $\forall x(Fx\to Gx)$};
\node at (2.1,0.6) { $G$ };
% \draw (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (4.5,2.5) node [text=black,above] {$\emptyset$};
\draw (5,0) circle (1cm) node { $F$ };
\draw (7.5,0) circle (1cm) node { $G$ };
\node[anchor=south,rectangle] at (6.25,1) { No $F$ are $G$ \\ $\forall x(Fx\to \neg Gx)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
%\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\path (0,2); %<- added
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm) node { $F$ };
\draw (1.5,0) circle (1cm) node { $G$ };
\draw (0.8,0) node { \textbf{x} };
\node[anchor=south,rectangle] at (0.75,1) { Some $F$ are $G$ \\ $\exists x(Fx\wedge Gx)$};
\draw (5,0) circle (1cm) node { $F$ };
\draw (6.5,0) circle (1cm) node { $G$ };
\draw (5,-0.65) node { \textbf{x} };
\node[anchor=south,rectangle] at (5.75,1) { Some $F$ are not $G$ \\ $\exists x(Fx\wedge \neg Gx)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{The four standard types of quantified statements\label{venn}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, there are much advanced ways to do this. For instance, you could use a `matrix`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle [radius=0.6cm]}
\def\secondcircle{(0,0) circle [radius=1cm]}

\colorlet{circle edge}{black}
\colorlet{circle area}{gray!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick}, outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\begin{figure}
\footnotesize\centering
% Set A and B
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/whatever/.style={code={#1}}]
\matrix[cells={nodes={anchor=center,align=center}},column sep=2em]{
\node {All $F$ are $G$\\ $\forall x(Fx\to Gx)$}; & 
\node {No $F$ are $G$\\ $\forall x(Fx\to \neg Gx)$}; \\
\pic{whatever={
\draw[filled] \firstcircle node { $F$ };
\draw \secondcircle node { };
\node at (45:0.8) { $G$ };
}}; &
\pic{whatever={\draw (-1.25,0) circle [radius=1cm] node { $F$ };
\draw (1.25,0) circle [radius=1cm] node { $G$ };
}}; \\[2em] 
\node{Some $F$ are $G$\\ $\exists x(Fx\wedge Gx)$};
&
\node{Some $F$ are not $G$ \\ $\exists x(Fx\wedge \neg Gx)$};
\\
\pic{whatever={\draw (-0.75,0) circle [radius=1cm] node { $F$ };
\draw (0.75,0) circle [radius=1cm] node { $G$ };
\draw (0,0) node { \textbf{x} };
}};
&
\pic{whatever={
\draw (-0.75,0) circle [radius=1cm] node { $F$ };
\draw (0.75,0) circle [radius=1cm] node { $G$ };
\draw (-0.75,-0.65) node { \textbf{x} };
}};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The four standard types of quantified statements\label{venn}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You great...Thanks a lot...

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer I do not know if you have heard about that virus, but we cats do not like to catch one of those. While the mask does not really help, it reminds others to be more careful.

Comment: Okey. Thank  you!